# Multiple Feedback Filter

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, active-filter

I built a Multiple Feedback low pass filter on the breadboard using an LM7171. Below is the schematics:
[image]

While doing measurements, I noticed two things:

1. Large DC bias at the input R3 and the output of the op amp.
2. The signal at the output is severely attenuated even at low frequencies.

I ran a frequency response analysis and below are the results obtained:
[image]

The response is not for a low pass filter. The gain of the signal seems to increase as frequency go up.

Any Idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are the supply voltages to the Op-amp connected in the right way?

Comment: The supply voltages are correct. I did check that. Besides if they were wrong, the op amp would have been destroyed by now. LM7171 pin 4 is negative and pin 7 is positive.

Comment: If bias is the problem, try adding a series capacitor of a few uF, to block the DC.

Comment: Have you calculated what behaviour you expect from this circuit, using math?

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that the power supplies are backwards. Pin 4 is for - and pin 7 is +.

When working with op amps first make sure the DC voltages are correct.  If the biasing is wrong, the op amp is not operating correctly and frequency response means nothing.

Comment: I apologize for the schematics. I just put it quickly for demonstration. I could assure you the supply voltages on the breadboard are correct.